# ScrollView, smooth scroll listener

Tags: android, scrollview, smooth-scrolling, onscrollchanged

I need to listen to the scroll of a `ScrollView`. In order to do that I extended the ScrollView overriding its `onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int)`.

When the view scrolls I move another view along with that scroll, and all is ok. When I release the view while scrolling, the ScrollView still scrolls with an inertia effect (smooth scroll). The problem is that, after the release, the method `onScrollChanged` is called after the view is invalidated, the effect is that my view is moved after a small delay with an ugly effect.

In order to avoid this I could disable the smooth scroll from the ScrollView. But, is there a way for listening for the smooth scroll and continuing moving the view also during the residual scroll?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it but it's a different way of getting scroll position change.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(listener);
```

this listener is a simple interface:

```
public void onScrollChanged(){
    scrollView.getscrollY(); // value is here
}
```

Comment: I found that overriding ScrollView's onScrollChanged was a better solution, but both these two solutions do not solve my problem... thanks